# c# sending control shortcuts

Tags: c#, xaml, controls, newline

I am making a program in c sharp/xaml. I have a save button, and figured the easiest way to make it effective was when pressed if I could send the "control s" signal. What is the command (and any includes VS wouldn't add as standard) to do so?

A completely different question to cut down on thread count, how would I make a textblock (or textbox if easier) automatically newline when you reach the end rather than continuing to send text offscreen.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Could you rephrase / add info? 1) Do you mean "event"? 2) textboxes don't use threads, they are handled by a single shared GUI thread.

Comment: WPF. I was refering to the threads on this forum. I have a button called save. When the user pushes the button, it calls a button press event and inside that event I want to make the computer think the user pressed control s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better patterns that I would suggest looking into before coupling your UI to keypresses (such as [Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)) but if you really want to do this, you can use the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class from windows forms. This will allow you to send key presses to the application as if the user pressed those keys.

As for the second question, if you're using WPF just create a textbox element and set `AcceptsReturn="True"` and `TextWrapping="Wrap"`. Here's an example:

```
<TextBox
  Name="tbMultiLine"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
>
  This TextBox will allow the user to enter multiple lines of text.  When the RETURN key is pressed, 
  or when typed text reaches the edge of the text box, a new line is automatically inserted.
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SaveFileDialog() .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When user clicks button, show the dialog.
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get file name.
        string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        // Write to the file name selected.
        // ... You can write the text from a TextBox instead of a string literal.
        File.WriteAllText(name, "test");
    }
```

Comment: would it not be easier to just send a control signal than have a 2nd function? I also had need for several other control signals but didn't feel I needed to list them all if I specifically asked for how to send a control signal.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAML I'll assume you're using WPF. So you should be able to bind the `Command` property of the Button to [`ApplicationCommands.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.save.aspx).